# External jar as Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let say I have an external jar named `data-access-0.0.1.jar` that contains Spring annotation like `@Component`, `@Bean`. But this jar does NOT contain the main method to run as a Spring application (means no `@SpringBootApplication`, no `@ComponentScan, ...).`

Now I have another jar named `employee.0.0.1.jar` (does have the main method to run as Spring boot application - `@SpringBootApplication)`, that use `data-access-0.0.1.jar` as a dependency. But somehow it does not scan `@Bean, @Component` in an external jar (error when starting the app, no bean with type `"myComponent`" found).

I think `@ComponentScan` in `employee-0.0.1.jar` should configure base packages include a package from the external jar and it should work, but I do not want to apply this mechanism. I want to somehow configure in the external jar so that any another jar that depend on it should scan the whole jar for autowiring

Comment: Define the packages on the final jar in a way that matches the application that will run (employee) i.e. your employee package scan is `com.something.employee` and your data access is `com.somethingelse.dataaccess` instead define data access as `com.something.dataaccess` and change componentscan to `com.something` that will work. Otherwise it is not magic, the application that runs is the one that knows which context it should load and from where. There is no way for you to add an external jar that injects itself into your application without changing anything in your app other than pkg sugges

Comment: Perhaps you want to [write your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).